# refreshing audios makes them impossible to listen to

Tags: django, vue.js, v-for

I want to make a whatsapp like message app but only with audios. I can get them in my vue app the by refreshing regularly the store, to see if new audios arrived:

```
 refresh() {
   this.$store.dispatch("audio/getAudios");

 },
},
created() {
   setInterval(this.refresh, 1000);
},
```

and I display them the following way in my vue app:

```
<div class="audios" v-for="audio in audios" :key="audio">
 <audio controls v-if="audio.rooms.split(',').includes(room)">
  <source :src= "'http://localhost:8000'+audio.audiofile" type="audio/wav">
 </audio> 
 </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that by refreshing every second, all audios that are displayed are 're'-displayed and it makes impossible to listen to them. How can I use the v-for differently to avoid this trouble ?

Answer (score 0):

putting audio.id as key solved my problem